# getting command output assigned to variable (BASH)

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm running a command which basically parses some JSON and then extracts an ID using awk and sed.

When I run the command on its own it give the correct output eg

```
cat CustomThemeProfile.json | sed -e 's/[{}]/''/g' | awk -v k="text" '{n=split($0,a,","); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i]}' | awk -F ":" '{print $0}' | grep id | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | sed 's/\"//g'
2F13F732-4BCB-49DC-A0FB-C91B5DE58472
```

But when I want to assign the output to a variable I get nothing returned. eg

```
cat CustomThemeProfile.json | id=$(sed -e 's/[{}]/''/g' | awk -v k="text" '{n=split($0,a,","); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i]}' | awk -F ":" '{print $0}' | grep id | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | sed 's/\"//g'); echo $id
```

Any ideas.  I really want this to be ran from a script but for the moment the script just does nothing, sits waiting for something?

Script i'm calling from.

First script just finds all json files and then calls this script.  so the file is passed

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "running search and replace script ..."

id="$(sed -e 's/[{}]/''/g' | awk -v k="text" '{n=split($0,a,","); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i]}' | awk -F ":" '{print $0}' | grep id | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | sed 's/\"//g')"
filler="0-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"

echo $id

if [ $(#id) -ge 8]; then echo "New Profile ID in use"; exit
else idnew=$id$filler
fi

sed -i '"s/$id/$idnew/g"' $1

sed -i 's/ps_hpa/ps_hpa/g' $1
```

Comment: There are a couple of errors that would be picked up by http://www.shellcheck.net - I suggest that you use that and tidy up your script so that we can focus on the specific problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rearrange your syntax a little bit:

```
id=$(sed -e 's/[{}]/''/g' CustomThemeProfile.json | awk -v k="text" '{n=split($0,a,","); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i]}' | awk -F ":" '{print $0}' | grep id | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | sed 's/\"//g')
```

Notice I am avoiding a useless use of cat and passing the file directly to sed. This is why your script does nothing - sed is waiting for some input. It would be possible to move cat inside the command substitution but there's no advantage to doing so. If a tool is capable of reading a file itself, then you should use that capability.

The better solution would be to parse your JSON properly, using `jq` for example. In order for us to show you how to do that, you should edit your question to show us a sample of your input.

Comment: Thanks Tom,  when i run your command i still get nothing returned.

Comment: I will add the script i'm calling this from to the question so you can see whats happening

Comment: @Damian the sed command in your script isn't being passed anything (and those `''` aren't doing anything useful, by the way).

Comment: Thanks Tom, added $1 as the input to the first sed statement and now id is being set.

Comment: Better yet you should add `"$1"` - see my comment above :).